# Как форматировать текст который ввел пользователь?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Всем привет, решил написать бота, но встретился с проблемкой. Пользователь вводит форматированный текст боту, а бот должен вывести тот же текст с форматированием, но он выводит обычный текст без форматирования. Как можно отправить текст пользователя с форматированием? parse_mode='HTML'/'Markdown' не помог. Заранее спасибо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

М... Не занимался сам этим на Питоне, но бегло, на вскидку:

```
import requests

apiToken = 'ХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХ'
chatID = 'ХХХХХХХХХХ'
apiURL = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{apiToken}/sendMessage'

message = '<b>Привет</b> <s>из скрипта</s> <i>на Python!</i>'
try:
    response = requests.post(apiURL, json={'chat_id': chatID, 'parse_mode': 'html', 'text': message}) 
    print(response.text)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]